# MYSQL triggers/procedures returning 0 in count query for a table even if there are records in that table

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-workbench, mysql-connector

In MYSQL Triggers , we check count for rows of table with where clause. Depending on that we have condition to only populate other table if row count is 0. So, if there are one or more rows in the table and we fire the query directly (without INTO) then we get count as 1 which is fair. But if we fire the same through trigger or procedure then we get count as 0. To debug the trigger I had put put the condition in stored procedure and found count was getting 0 even if there were rows in table
Could you please help with with the issue

Count query -

```
SELECT COUNT(1) INTO RepCnt 
FROM REPLICATIONAUDIT 
WHERE (LTRIM(RTRIM(LOWER(REPLICATIONDESCRIPTION))) = 'full replication' OR LTRIM(RTRIM(LOWER(REPLICATIONDESCRIPTION))) LIKE '%base replication%') AND REPLICATIONSTATUSID = 1;
```

Comment: I suspect there is an inconsistency in the WHERE-clause COULD you please try  WHERE (LTRIM(RTRIM(LOWER(REPLICATIONDESCRIPTION))) = 'full replication' OR (  LTRIM(RTRIM(LOWER(REPLICATIONDESCRIPTION))) LIKE '%base replication%') AND REPLICATIONSTATUSID = 1 );

Comment: *But if we fire the same through trigger or procedure then we get count as 0.* Do you query in AFTER trigger?

Comment: Provide complete example: CREATE TABLE, INSERT INTO with initial data, CREATE TRIGGER, the query which fires the trigger, desired final data state. Or create online fiddle with the issue.